# store and retrieve cookie values in C#

Tags: c#, cookies

I have a slot machine application which displays a flash file using c#. Any user would come to the site and play the game. But I would need to limit that a max of 3 times per day, meaning he could play the game only 3 times and if he goes to play the fourth time, then he would get a message indicating he could play the next day. Since there is no user login on this site, i have decided to store cookie values. It would be counter that would increment each time he gets into the site. Then, on each page_load event, retrieve the cookie value and if its 3, then display the No Play Message.

First i would retrieve the value of cookie on page load event.

```
string _counter = response.Cookies["slotmachinecookie"]["counter"];
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
    if (_counter) = 3
       //displayMessage
       return;
    else
    {
       HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("slotmachinecookie");
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_counter))
         cookie.Values.Add("1", "counter");
       else if (_counter == "1")
         cookie.Values.Add("2", "counter")
       else if (_counter == "2")
         cookie.Values.Add("3", "counter");
    }
}
```

Will this work? I guess i could try it but just want to make sure if there is a better way other than cookies to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I guess i could try it...` I think you are heading in the right direction. :)

Comment: hehe, thanks Paul. Just wondering if there is any other ways..thanks!! I will give this a try.

Comment: Don't forget that a user, once they figure out you're keeping track of their usage via cookies, can just clear cookies and keep playing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my comment, your approach will work, but a savvy user could outwit your usage limitation by clearing cookies and continue playing all day long.

While the cookie approach is easy, it does have a hole in it.

What you may want to consider is capturing the user's incoming IP address and storing it in a database, or local cache (depending on how your application is architected), or some other repository.

You can capture the incoming IP address by using the server request variable `REMOTE_ADDR`.

```
Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

Again, based on how your app is hosted, your provider may not report this correctly (e.g. if your server is behind a load balancer, which may be the IP of the load balancer).  You may also want to check if your provider forwards this information using a "X_FORWARDED_FOR" header.  (Some devices use different variations on the name of this header...check your documentation.)

So this will be a little more complex, but also will be able to close that hole a bit more to limit usage to only 3 times a day.

I hope this helps.  Good luck!

Comment: This one also has a hole: if the user turns off and on his cable modem will likely get a new IP address and then this check will fail too. On the other hand, I don't think there's anything else he can do, so either this approach or the cookie one are pretty much his only alternatives.

Comment: Small correction - it's actually `Request.ServerVariables`, not `Request.Server`. But I personally prefer `Request.UserHostAddress`, which gets you the same thing but is compile-safe.

Comment: @Joe Enos - thanks...corrected the code.  Guess I shouldn't go off my memory too much anymore.  :)

Comment: @Icarus - good point.  Although that's not always the case.  I've had to reboot my cable modem a number of times here at home in the past 3 months and my IP hasn't changed (and I don't have a static IP address).  It's probably just luck, and it is a good point.  You can't rely on the IP being constant.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see where you are checking the date and resetting the count to zero if it's a new day.

And, is it per day or per 24 hour period?